# Problem setting variable in EC2 User Data from lambda (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

Having a strange problem. I'm passing user data to my EC2 from Lambda:

```
var userData= `#!/bin/bash
echo 'bar' > /tmp/bar
echo 'foo' > /tmp/foo
myvar=980549805498054089598
echo $myvar >> /temp/foo
`;

var userDataEncoded = new Buffer.from(userData).toString('base64');

var instanceParams = { 
    InstanceType: 't2.nano',
    ...
    UserData: userDataEncoded
};
```

The files are created correctly and 'bar' appears inside bar. But inside foo, I only see 'foo'. No sign of the variable I made. Also, if I run

```
$ echo $myvar
```

I don't get anything for it?! It's very strange. It's like some parts of the user data script are executed, but other bits aren't! Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: You seem to write `$myvar` to `/temp/foo` instead of `/tmp/foo`.

Comment: @snak. Oh! That'll explain the first point. Now why is myvar not accessible in the instance? I suppose, it doesn't actually matter so long as it is accessible inside the script, since that's where it's used. I only went looking for it in an effort to figure out what went wrong (which you have now explained).

Comment: It's because shell variables are only available in the process of the shell which executes the script. When you login to the instance via ssh, for example, you're running another shell, in which you cannot access these variables. You need to declare them as environment variables in `/etc/profile`, for example, to access them.